# longest path two nodes in common

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a **connected** graph. Prove that two longest paths in $G$ have atleast one node in common. Note that two longest paths do not neccessarily have the same length.

I began by defining two paths namely $P_1 = <v_1,...,v_k>$ and $P_2 =<u_1,...,u_m>$ where $m\neq k$ because of the note given. Now I state the definition of a conneted graph.

> A graph G is connected if for each pair of vertices u; v, there is a u; v-walk
>   in G.

now my first intuition is to consider the fact that if no node was shared than connecting the two paths would give a (slightly ?) longer path which would make them not the largest paths. Given the fact that they are the two largest (say $n$ and $n-1$). They should be connected via atleast one node.

HOWEVER it seems odd for me to now state that this is a proof.

Comment: Huh? What is the definition of "longest path" if a path can be "longest" without being, well, longest? Perhaps "of maximal length/inextensible" (but that seems unlikely since the answer is easily seen to be wrong in that case)?

Comment: im considering the case where there is NOT a node shared, thus disjoint.  which gives my a contradiction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P_1 = \langle v_0, \dots, v_m \rangle$ and $P_2 = \langle u_0, \dots, u_n \rangle$, such that $P_1$ and $P_2$ have no common vertices, be two different longest inextensible paths in a graph. Let us assume that $m \ge n$. Furthermore, let $v_k$ and $u_l$ be connected (in the original graph) be a path $\langle v_k, w_1, \dots, w_p, u_l \rangle$ such that neither of $w_i$ belong to either $P_1$ or $P_2$ (the length of such path is, obviously, $p+1$).

Without the loss of generality, we can assume that $k \ge m/2$ and $l \ge n/2$. This is just a matter of notation: we're labeling vertices in a way that $\langle v_0, \dots, v_k \rangle$ is longer than or equally long as $\langle v_k, \dots, v_m \rangle$ and that $\langle u_1, \dots, u_l \rangle$ is longer than or equally long as $\langle u_l, \dots, u_n \rangle$.

We construct a new path
$$P := \langle v_0, \dots, v_k, w_1, \dots, w_p, u_l, \dots u_0 \rangle$$
which has length
$$k + (p + 1) + l \ge m/2 + p + 1 + n/2 \ge n/2 + p + 1 + n/2 = n + p + 1 > n,   $$
so $P$ is strictly longer than $P_2$ (and obviously different from $P_1$), which is a contradiction with the assumption that $P_2$ is the second longest inextensible path in the graph.

Comment: let me reread this. what is inextensible? why do we assume m\geq n ?

Comment: Inextensible means you cannot add more vertices to it (both ends are "dead ends", i.e. connected to nothing or only to the vertices in the same path). We assume that $m \ge n$ simply to state that $P_1$ is the longest, while $P_2$ may be a bit shorter. It's another "without the loss of generality" assumption to make it more clear which is which.

Comment: My god, I love it. Have a cookie. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Should it not be $m > n$ seeing as if $m=n$ then we would have to choose another path to be chosen? They have to be strictly smaller I assume.

Comment: You would then need to prove that they cannot be of equal length and we don't need that, so why make it harder on ourselves? ;-) But, imagine a graph with 5 vertices, shaped as "X", with each end of "X" and a crossing being a vertex. You have 2 different inextensible paths of the same length, so $m = n$.

Comment: I am however having trouble concluding from your final sentence that we need to have a conneting node. Could I say "Because of this contradiction arising from the absence of the common node, it would only hold when given the common node"

Comment: Not a "common node". Nodes $v_k$ and $v_l$ are each in their own paths, but are connected in the graph. These must exist, since the graph is connected. I did make a slight mistake here: they don't have to be directly connected. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I've fixed it now. Think of a graph shaped like "H", with vertical lines being very long, but the horizontal one being of length 2 (i.e. one vertex on each of the long "vertical" paths and one vertex in the middle). The proof should be O.K. now.

Comment: @VedranŠego In the "Furthermore, let..." sentence, how can you be sure that there is a path "such that neither of $w_i$ belong to either $P_1$ or $P_2$"

Comment: @Arthur Because they are connected. Not that I make no assumptions on $p$, meaning that it can be zero. The final inequality would still get to $n+1>n$, thus proving what we need. Basically, the idea is to connect the two paths (either via more vertices or directly). The points $v_k$ and $u_l$ through which you connect them are somewhere in their middles (as you cannot just extend them), dividing each in two parts. You take longer ones of those, and obtain a new path which is longer than the one we assumed to be the second longest,

Comment: @VedranŠego I believe I was not clear enough. I was not questioning the existence of a path connecting two of those vertices, afterall we are assuming that the graph is connected. I questioned the existence of a path "such that none of the $w_i$ belong to either $P_1$ or $P_2$" I believe we should first assert that for every $v_i$ and $u_j$ there is a path connecting them (including those on the extremes of the path, afterall the graph is connected, the thing is if we get a path connecting the extremes we will not have the desired property) then get a minimal path.

Comment: Only then we'd prove that a minimal path is "such that none of the $w_i$ belong to either $P_1$ or $P_2$"

Comment: @Arthur Assume that this assumption is false. There must be the last $w_i$ in $P_1$, let's call it $w_*$. Remove from the path the part from $w_1$ to $w_*$ and label $w_*$ as $v_k$. Relabel $w_i$ nodes to go from $w_1$. Now, none of the (remaining) $w_i$ belong to $P_1$, while there is still $v_k \in P_1$ that is connected to $w_1$. Do the same at the end of of the path $\langle w_i \rangle$ with $P_2$ and you get exactly what I claimed above.